# Startup manager for macOS - alternatives to now defunct Startupizer and DelayedLauncher?

Tags: osx, macos

[Startupizer](http://gentlebytes.com/startupizer/) has been a wonderful app that still kind of works, but has a number of broken features, not the least of which is hiding apps at startup. Sadly it's no longer maintained.

Another one that is fairly decent, but also abandoned and [has been open sourced](https://github.com/taoeffect/DelayedLauncher) is [DelayedLauncher](https://www.taoeffect.com/blog/2010/03/delayedlauncher-2-0/).